# Error when simulating baxter in gazebo

Tags: ros, baxter, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch `baxter_world` I get the following errors in order. I'm struggling with fixing these.

```
[ INFO] [1448157761.777717835]: getting bounds for joint: [right_s0]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [baxter_sim_hardware/baxter_emulator]: can't locate node [baxter_emulator] in package [baxter_sim_hardware]

[INFO] [WallTime: 1448157762.755704] [0.000000] Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1010] multiple inconsistent <self_collide> exists due to fixed joint reduction overwriting previous value [true] with [false].
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 8359, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/veyorokon/.ros/log/1c64b260-90bd-11e5-b392-b8e85645ebf8/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/veyorokon/.ros/log/1c64b260-90bd-11e5-b392-b8e85645ebf8/gazebo_gui-3*.log

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 8353, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/veyorokon/ros/baxter_ws/src/baxter_simulator/baxter_gazebo/worlds/baxter.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/veyorokon/.ros/log/1c64b260-90bd-11e5-b392-b8e85645ebf8/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/veyorokon/.ros/log/1c64b260-90bd-11e5-b392-b8e85645ebf8/gazebo-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221333/error-when-simulating-baxter-in-gazebo/) by [veyorokon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25149/veyorokon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on 2015-11-22**:
Which branch of baxter_simulator and all baxter repos are you using? Make sure the are all on the same branch. The first error makes it seem like either baxter_gazebo wasn't built with catkin or the environment wasn't sourced again after the build. Have you tried a fresh build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a tough since the error doesn't provide many details as to the actual problem. I left a comment to rule out some common errors, but I suspect your Linux graphics card is the likely culprit. Try switching to a proprietary driver using the Troubleshooting page of the Baxter wiki: http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Gazebo_Troubleshooting

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2015-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1